# How to Create a Clickable Widget with a Dynamic surface area?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

My objective is to make a small widget that changes shape considering a single value (bottom bar).
I made this shape variation with a `drawPoligon` inside a `paintEvent`:

https://i.gyazo.com/ecbe701c15c24f069101bbe17a6bbf93.mp4

This widget will act like a color picker:

[image] (example)

however I still have some limitations I don't know how to pass through yet.

My question kinda boils around these 2 points:

1- Previously I used CSS Style sheets on my QtDesigner UI made widget to paint the `background-color`, however I need to:

- mask color sections of the widget
- make it "unclickable" outside that area
- paint the area with a polygonal shape that I can adjust the points.

2- I have used `self.setMask()` but it does not seem to affect the style sheet background color. if it does I do not know how to set it up properly. I also did attempts with `clip_path` and `background-clip` with poor or no results.

I have tryed with the `drawPolygon` shape I made but It creates a issue with the alpha of the SVG cursor I have. leaving a trail on the drawn Polygon until I update it again. if this is the way I would need a way to handle this issue to go around it.

[image]

I made a custom polygon that does the weird behavior on the video this is just a sample one on the example.

What I got so far:

```
background-color: rgb(85, 170, 127);
clip-path:polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: A widget like that needs to be a custom widget that draws a (possibly) QTransform[ed] polygon using a QLinearGradient. I developed something like this in the past, but to be able to really help you you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've got so far.

Comment: if you want I can update my addon on Github and then you can use it on Krita if you have that program installed. I posted the paintEvent I have for the time being but this is just to see the correct area for the surface on the widget.

Comment: You already know that here on SO we have to try to keep the code as simple as possible, without relying on external resources. Since the painted widget also reacts to mouse events, you should either use a common "mapping" object/property or use a QGraphicsScene item to interact with that. As far as I can remember, it's been at least two months since you're trying to build your own custom "plugin", and, each time, you provide too little code to work with, also showing too little experience on trying to do what you want to achieve. We can't help you if you don't help us.

Comment: the idea situation for me would be to plug this QPolygon into a CSS style sheet to clip the background color.

Comment: I will try and make a shorter sample.

Comment: Since that triangle is going to rotate, you shouls avoid a simple `setMask()`, and use a mousePressEvent instead.

Comment: it is not the mouse that changes the hexagon but the slider underneath it, mousePressEvent is currently handling the cursor of the picker and emission of signals. the setMask kinda does everything I need it just not interacts with the style sheet to help with the display. I need to read on QGraphicsScene to see how it works.